# FPDF Custom page size is not working properly

Tags: php, fpdf

I wanted to print a page on FPDF that has the size of 40x30mm for barcode stickers when I tried it, I'm getting the wrong output.

[image]

Here is my code

```
$orientation = 'P';
$unit = 'mm';
$size = array(40,30);
$page_width = $size[0];
$pdf = new Barcode128($orientation, $unit,$size);

//the rest of pdf...
```

The image below is the expected output but I had to make it on landscape which is not ideal since it will be crop off on the sticker.

[image]

Comment: `$size` should be defined as `array(30,40)`.

Comment: I already tried, but I got the same output with its contents compressed.